# Are electric charge $U(1)$ and baryon number $U(1)$ parameterized by the same phase?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, standard-model, noethers-theorem

Both of them are described as conservation due to the symmetry of an overall phase change (to the same spinor, I assume). But yet they are different properties.

Another way to ask this question is: can the phase related to electric charge conservation and the phase related to baryon number conservation be added or substracted?

Answer (score 3):

If we rotate the phase all charged particles by an angle $\theta$ times their charge, and rotate the phase of all baryons by an angle $\phi$ times their baryon number, then the Lagrangian is invariant (hence there is a symmetry).

Let's consider one field $\Phi_1$ (of any spin) with charge $q_1$ and baryon number $B_1$. Then under the joint charge and baryon transformation, this field transforms as
\begin{equation}
\Phi_1 \rightarrow e^{i q_1 \theta} e^{i B_1 \phi} \Phi_1 = e^{i (q_1\theta + B_1 \phi)} \Phi_1
\end{equation}
So in that sense, the rotated angles add.

However, take another field $\Phi_2$ with charge $q_2$ and baryon number $B_2$. This field transforms as
\begin{equation}
\Phi_2 \rightarrow e^{i q_2 \theta} e^{i B_2 \phi} \Phi_2 = e^{i (q_2\theta + B_2 \phi)} \Phi_2
\end{equation}
There is no way to write the rotated phase of both $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ as (some field-dependent constant) times (one field-independent angle). There's nothing wrong with this, but it reflects the fact that these are two separate symmetries as opposed to one larger symmetry. In other words, symmetry group is a product of simpler symmetries $U(1)\times U(1)$, rather than being a 2-dimensional group that cannot be decomposed into simpler pieces.

On the other hand, if we only consider a charge rotation, or only consider a baryon rotation, we can consider the transformation to involve one parameter which is universal for all fields undergoing the transformation, and a set of constants for each field.

Comment: Thanks! I could only guessed this is the case before your answer. Where can I find discussions like this in the textbooks?

Comment: @王凯越KaiyueWang Unfortunately a lot of little details like this are considered "obvious" in QFT books. It's not for a bad reason; there are so many details in QFT that you have to make a cut somewhere. This is one of the reasons self-study is so hard; having a teacher and other students to discuss things with always helps to fill in the gaps. Having said that, this general structure is a [direct product of (Abelian) groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_product_of_groups) and worth knowing.

Comment: Another question @Andrew: what does it mean when \(U_B(1)\) is broken but \(U_{EM}(1)\) is not. This is the case in color superconductivity's CFL phase. If U_B is spontaneously broken into \(\mathbb{Z}(2)\) that means the ground state turns into a different state when we add an arbitrary overall phase that's not \(\pi\), but if \(U_{EM}\)  is not broken that indicates that it is still the same state after the change of phase. So I am confused how different symmetry breaking can be possible.

Comment: Also what does not convince me, is that U(1) \times U(1) should be isomorphic to a torus, but if we simply add the phases together, it is still isomorphic to the circle.

Comment: @王凯越KaiyueWang There are two different phases, which in my answer I called $\theta$ (associated with charge) and $\phi$ (baryon number), that can be chosen independently. (a) If baryon number is spontaneously broken in some state, it means that after transforming the fields by $e^{i b_i \phi}$, observables will depend on $\phi$ in that state. (b) In physics we normally refer to the local properties of a group instead of a topology. But if we take all the charges equal for simplicity, the state will come back to itself under $\phi \rightarrow \phi+2\pi/b$ and $\theta\rightarrow \theta+2\pi/q$.

Comment: In other words, the topology of the symmetry group really is a torus, because the symmetry group really is $U(1)\times U(1)$, even though often physicists are lazy about tracking this kind of global structure. (This would be subtle if the charges were irrational numbers, but in practice the charge and baryon number are all integer multiples of some base unit so the statement in my comment above can be generalized to the case of realistic values of the electric charge and baryon number for multiple fields in the standard model)

Comment: How do you use LaTeX in comments btw?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128008/discussion-between-andrew-and--kaiyue-wang).